# How can use cover flow in portrait mode in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, coverflow, portrait

I want to use cover flow in portrait mode in iPhone SDK, can it is possible ?

Please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m)

and for orientation use below code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    //return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
//          (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));

    return NO;
}
```

in "FlowCoverViewController.m"

Thanks

Comment: link of chaosinmotion is broken